# How to uninstall compizconfig?

Tags: 11.10, compiz

I setup the compizconfig, but I find I don't like it.

and my terminal cant use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>v</kbd> since I setup the compizconfig?

So how to uninstall it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can't you just do -

```
sudo apt-get remove compizconfig-settings-manager
```

Comment: This command should indeed get rid of it, assuming `compizconfig` is the package name.

Answer (score 2):

**This is what i used when i had a problem with it.**

Or you could use:

```
sudo apt-get remove compiz-fusion-plugins-extra
sudo apt-get remove compiz-plugins-extra
sudo apt-get purge compiz*
```

Then to Re-install use:

```
sudo apt-get install unity-2d
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop-2d
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
sudo apt-get install xserver-xgl
sudo apt-get install emerald
sudo apt-get install compiz-fusion-plugins-extra
sudo apt-get install git compiz-plugins-extra
sudo apt-get install compiz-plugins-extra
sudo apt-get install unity
```